# display form main page and action page in wordpress for plugin frontend side user

Tags: php, forms, plugins, wordpress, custom-pages

I have created one plugin which inserts vehicles to DB table,displays vehicles at admin side from that table.One page is for settings of that plugin.admin side of plugin is mostly complete.now i want to display a form for taxi booking.when user submit that form in action page, i want to display google map with locations and distance with payment option.i googled it but not found best way.How sholud i create plugin front side?from where should I start?can anyone suggest me?

this is the form that i want to display at front side

```
<form name="book_form" id="book_form" action="" method="POST">
        <!--<input type="hidden" name="action" value="tBM_taxibooking_save_booking" />-->
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th>Select Location Points On Google Map</th>
                    <td>
                        <select name="location_points" id="location_points">
                            <option value="points">Points</option>
                            <option value="2">2</option>
                            <option value="3">3</option>
                            <option value="4">4</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>First Address Point</th>
                    <td><input type="text" name="first_point" id="first_point"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Second Address Point</th>
                    <td><input type="text" name="second_point" id="second_point"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Third Address Point</th>
                    <td><input type="text" name="third_point" id="third_point"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Fourth Address Point</th>
                    <td><input type="text" name="fourth_point" id="fourth_point"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Adult Seats</th>
                    <td>
                        <select name="adult" id="adult">
                            <option value="Adult Seats">Adult Seats</option>
                            <?php
                                $i=1;
                                for($i=1;$i<=10;$i++)
                                {   echo'<option value="'.$i.'">'.$i.'</option>';   }
                            ?>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Child Seats</th>
                    <td>
                        <select name="child" id="child">
                            <option value="Child Seats">Child Seats</option>
                            <?php
                                $i=1;
                                for($i=1;$i<=10;$i++)
                                {   echo'<option value="'.$i.'">'.$i.'</option>';   }
                            ?>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Suitcases</th>
                    <td>
                        <select name="suitcases" id="suitcases">
                            <option value="Suitcases">Suitcases</option>
                            <?php
                                $i=1;
                                for($i=1;$i<=50;$i++)
                                {   echo'<option value="'.$i.'">'.$i.'</option>';   }
                            ?>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Select Vehicle</th>
                    <td>
                        <select name="vehicle" id="vehicle">
                            <option value="vehicles">Select Vehicle</option>
                            <?php
                                while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($results))
                                {
                                    echo'<option value="'.$row['vechicle_id'].'">'.$row['vechicle_title'].'</option>';
                                }
                            ?>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <td><input type="text" name="date" id="date"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Get Map & Distance" id="submit" name="submit"></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </form>
```